# VBA Test if Access linked table has #Num! errors

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to work out a way of telling if any of the fields have an #Num! error in any of the rows of a linked Excel table.

The only way I can think of is by dynamically building a query which shows records from the table where any of the fields are equal to `#Num!`and seeing if the count of records in that query is more than 0.

I have only limited control over what is being put in at the front end so I'm trying to put some extra validation into my part before I use the results.

The errors are due to input in a few of the cells in that column being text of numbers and access has looked at the column and decided it's numeric but then doesn't then like those cells.

Anyone think of any less intensive tests?

Comment: First thought is try and fix the underlying issue that causes the #Num! errors so you don't have to deal with the exception. Second idea if the first thought is not an option is to concatenate all the fields in the where clause of a SQL statement and specify `Not Like` "Num#!" or however the 'bad' data is interpreted by Access.

Comment: *trying to put some extra validation into my part before I use the results* .. what is *your part* and how are you using the results? If you're writing code or queries for the front end you have more than limited control.

Comment: I'm not writing queries on the front end. They have to be spreadsheets, I can't change that. My part is to take them, export them as CSV files and then sftp them elsewhere. That bit works fine but the #Num! cells are exported as nulls.

Comment: Update your question with that important fact - you're only using Access to export linked excel files to CSV format? So you have full control of the Access database and how it reads and exports the data? You must be using macros or VBA, correct?

Comment: The export has to be in CSV format without any text qualifiers. I am using VBA, it's in the title and is a tag. The question does state that I am thinking of dynamically counting number of records in each Excel sheet where any of the columns have the error text, I'm fairly sure you'd only be able to do that in VBA. I didn't want to include too much information that I deemed superfluous as I know it puts some people off to read very long posts. My export part is fine, I could post it but it's unlikely to add much to the main point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the solution [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208414) but for me it's not a very nice workaround. It leaves the linked excel in access having at least one row & column which I've then subsequently got around. You can't seem to pick up the #Num! in a query, if you do IsError([FieldName] it gives an error rather than True.

Comment: Link is dead.  Can you just list the potential solution?

Comment: I'll try and dig it out but that database build was the best part of 6 years ago so I'm a little rusty on it.